# Get List of files Using Powershell - Modified between two dates

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using following command to get all the files which were modified before 20 hours and after 20 days past..

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\server\c$\Program Files (x86)\folder'   -recurse -Filter *.* -include *.* |? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).Addhours(-20) }|? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-20)} | Select Fullname ,LASTWRITETIME | Sort-Object -Property LASTWRITETIME -Descending
```

It does gives me correct result.

But I'm getting Fullname as:

```
\\server\c$\Program Files (x86...
```

How can I get the fullname? Fullname is pretty long.. more than 260 character.

I've tried

```
Select -Expand Fullname
```

It works fine but i can't use it with LastWriteTime

```
Select -Expand Fullname, LastwriteTime
```

above command gives me error.

Comment: `Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: Do you need the full path onscreen or somewhere else useful ?

Comment: After using format-table I got this error: WARNING: column "LastWriteTime" does not fit into the display and was removed.

Comment: I tried using -Wrap with format-Table.. It shows fullname but it wraps the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format output using `Format-Table` cmdlet like this:

```
$table_properties = @{Expression={$_.Fullname};Label="Full Name";width=195}, 
                    @{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime};Label="Last Write Time";width=35}

Get-ChildItem -Path '\\server\c$\Program Files (x86)\folder'   -recurse -Filter *.* -include *.* |
? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).Addhours(-20) }|
? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-20)} | 
Sort-Object -Property LASTWRITETIME -Descending |
Format-Table $table_properties
```

Instead of `Select Fullname,LASTWRITETIME` create custom object `$table_properties` with formatting parameters and pass it to `Format-Table`.

If your string is wider than PowerShell host display width than pipe output to `Out-String -Width 500`, where 500 is enough characters to display all fields.

See [Creating custom tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx) article on TechNet.

Comment: I tried it.. it gives an error: WARNING: column "Last Write Time" does not fit into the display and was removed.